# php session values minimum of one value

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session, session-cookies

i am trying to create a computer based examination. i am storing the user selected answer as a php session using ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//if the button if check
$( ".form-check-input" ).on( "click", function() {

    var checkedvalue = $("input:checked" ).val();
    var ques = <?php echo $_SESSION['ques']; ?>;
    alert(ques);
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: { 
            ques:ques,
            checkedvalue:checkedvalue,
            request:"add"
            }
    }).done(function(count) {
        $( "#log" ).html(checkedvalue + " is checked2!" ).show();
        $( "#log2" ).html(count + " is checked2!" ).show();
        //  setTimeout(hideMessage, 2000);
    });
});
//$( ".form-check-input" ).attr("checked",false).html("is checked2!" ).show();
</script>
```

this is the ajax.php script

```
<?php
// START THE SESSION
session_start();

// CONFIGURATION
require("db.php");

$conn=new mysqli ($dbServername, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);

// PROCESS REQUESTS
switch ($_POST['request']) {
    case "add":
        // ITEMS WILL BE STORED IN THE ORDER OF
        // $_SESSION['cart'][PRODUCT ID] = QUANTITY

        if ($_POST['checkedvalue'] ==TRUE) {
            $_SESSION['option'][$_POST['ques']][$_POST['checkedvalue']] = 1;
            echo '<pre>';
            var_dump($_SESSION['option'][$_POST['ques']][$_POST['checkedvalue']]);
            echo '</pre>';
            echo $_SESSION['option'][$_POST['ques']][$_POST['checkedvalue']];
        }
        //here i am trying to checkif the user selects another answer which has been stored in the session so that it can remove the previously selected answer in the session          
        elseif($_SESSION['option'][$_POST['ques']][$_POST['checkedvalue']]>1){
            unset($_SESSION['option'][$_POST['ques']][$_POST['checkedvalue']]);
        }else {
            echo 'yes';
        }

        break;
```

this issue is that if the user unchecks an answer  the php session still saves but i cannot access that specific answer in the session array so as to unset that specific answer , then save the newly selected answer in the php session questions by question

htm

```html
<?php
session_start();

require("db.php");
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<Head>
<title>Examination Application</title>

<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">

                <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
     
</head>

<script src="jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body>
<?php// require 'opera.php' ?>

<?php



if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
 echo '<a href="?username=moses&page=1"><button class="btn btn-danger">START QUIZ</button></a>';

 $_SESSION['user'] =$_GET['username'];
 

}else{
//     if(isset($_POST['submit']))
//     {
//       // $submit=='Next Question' && isset($_POST['OPTION_A'])
//       $ans= $_POST['optradio'];
//       $ques= $_POST['ques'];
//      echo $ques;
//      echo $ans;
//      echo session_id();
//      $insertans = $conn->query("insert into useranswers(q_num, ans, session_id) values('$ques', '$ans','".session_id()."')") ;
//   if($insertans == TRUE){
//             echo 'inserted';
//         }else{
//             echo 'not inserted buddy';
//         }  

      
//     }else{
//         echo 'yes';
//     }
  
//    //unset($_SESSION['user']);
//    //session_destroy();

   // CONFIGURATION
   
   $url = $_GET['page'];
   echo $url;
if($_GET['page']==""){
    
//header("location:index.php");
    $num = 1;
    }else{
        $num = $_GET['page'];
    }
  $sql1 = "Select * from questions WHERE '$num' = q_num";
  $query_count=$conn->query($sql1);
  $res =$conn->query($sql1);
  while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
  $_SESSION['ques'] = $row['q_num'];
  
// echo '<form name="myform" method="POST" action="">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="ques" value="'.$row['q_num'].'"> ';
  echo '<div style="font-size:40px;padding:20px;  margin-top:40px;margin-left:55px; margin-right:40px; margin-right:40px;" >'.$row['q_num'].'.'.$row['ques'].'</div>';

?>
  <div class="form-check-inline">
  <label class="form-check-label">
  <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="optradio" value="<?php echo $row['OPTION_A'];?>"  <?php echo 'checked';?>  ><?php echo $row['OPTION_A'];?>
  </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check-inline">
  <label class="form-check-label">
  <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="optradio" value="<?php echo $row['OPTION_B'];?>" ><?php echo $row['OPTION_B'];?>
  </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check-inline ">
  <label class="form-check-label">
  <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="optradio" value="<?php echo $row['OPTION_C'];?>" ><?php echo $row['OPTION_C'];?>
  </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check-inline ">
  <label class="form-check-label">
  <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="optradio" value="<?php echo $row['OPTION_D'];?>"><?php echo $row['OPTION_D'];?>
  </label>
  </div>
  <?php
  }



  echo '<div id="log"></div>'; 
  echo '<div id="log2"></div>'; 



  if(isset($_SESSION['option']))
  {
    echo '<pre>';
  var_dump($_SESSION['option']);
  echo '</pre>';
  
    echo '<pre>' . print_r($_SESSION['option'], TRUE) . '</pre>';
  }else{
      echo 'nothing yet';
  }
}






?>
```

Comment: Try to avoid using PHP in JS, this is pretty bad practice, there are better ways to get external data into your JS without removing the ability to minify and cache your JS.

Comment: @BlessedMedia it doesn't have to be the answer, this is the comment section.

Comment: It would help us understand if you showed us he relevant HTML as well

Comment: okay @RiggsFolly

Comment: But as you are only passing the checked checkboxes, it looks like you will have to destroy this group in SESSION each time a new checkbox is checked and then recreate it with just the checked item

Comment: I've just checked and `$("input:checked" ).val();` will ONLY ever return 'on' or undefined, if its undefined then it it doesn't actually submit the data to PHP at all. This means by the time you get to PHP you're either working with the data 'on' or an undefined variable, your code does not take this into account as you're trying to do stuff with `$_POST['checkedvalue']` even when it doesn't exist.

Comment: i dont understand your last comment@RiggsFolly

Comment: i need help on how to unset Array
(
    [3] => Array
        (
            [something] => 1
            [culture] => 1
        )

)         //this is the result on the html page after user selecting two answers   //two answers has been selected but i need just one

Comment: i have inserted the html page @AlexanderDeSousa

Comment: I still need answer from developers

Answer (score 0):

Try binding change event on your checkbox instead of a click event. You would always receive the same for your checkbox (regardless checked or uncheck) on a click event for checkboxes.

```
$(".form-check-input").change(function() {
    // Perform ajax submission here
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: { 
            ques:ques,
            checkedvalue: this.checked,
            request:"add"
        }
    });
});
```

Then on your php side, you can update the appropriate values into your session depending on the "checked" variable from above.

```
if ($_POST["checkedvalue"]) {
    // Question is check
} else {
    // Question not check
}
```

Comment: Your initial true/false logic does nothing, you could just do: `checkedvalue: this.checked,` and skip all of that.

Comment: Much better, this addresses the issue of ensuring a true/false value is passed to PHP. However there are subsequent errors in the PHP logic that are not addressed.

Comment: Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [culture] => 1
            [something] => 1
        )

)   // it still saves more than one answer despite onchange

Comment: is there a way to prevent the session from having more than one array data

Comment: I still need answers please